# concatenate filepath prefix and file name in terraform code

Tags: loops, terraform, concatenation, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to create policies in aws with terraform.

```
variable "path" {
    type = "string"
}

variable "policies" {
    type = list(object ({
     name = string
     plcyfilename = string
     asmplcyfilename = string
     desc = string
     ownner = string}))
    default = []
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "policy" {
  count = length(var.policies)
  name =  lookup(var.policies[count.index], "name")
  policy = file(lookup(var.policies[count.index], concat("var.path","plcyfilename")))
  description = "Policy for ${lookup(var.policies[count.index], "desc")}"
}
```

and this is how my tfvars looks like:

```
path = "./../t2/scripts/"

policies =  [

{name = "cwpolicy", plcyfilename = "cw.json" , asmplcyfilename ="csasm.json", desc ="vpcflowlogs", ownner ="vpc"},

]
```

The error that is thrown while I do this is like this:

```
Error: Invalid function argument

  on main.tf line 13, in resource "aws_iam_policy" "policy":
  13:   policy = file(lookup(var.policies[count.index], "${concat("${var.path}","plcyfilename")}"))

Invalid value for "seqs" parameter: all arguments must be lists or tuples; got
string.
```

I'm using terraform 0.12.

It works as expected if I change the variable to have complete file path:`plcyfilename=./../t2/scripts/cw.json`.

However I want to isolate the file path from the file names.

Can someone point me where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `concat` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/concat.html) is for concatenating lists, not for concatenating strings.

To concatenate strings in Terraform, we use [template interpolation syntax](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#interpolation):

```
  policy = file("${var.path}/${var.policies[count.index].policy_filename}")
```

---

Since your collection of policies is not a sequence where the ordering is significant, I'd recommend also changing this to use [resource `for_each`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#for_each-multiple-resource-instances-defined-by-a-map-or-set-of-strings), which will ensure that Terraform tracks the policies using the policy name strings rather than using the positions in the list:

```
variable "policies" {
  type = map(object({
    policy_filename        = string
    assume_policy_filename = string
    description            = string
    owner                  = string
  }))
  default = {}
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "policy" {
  for_each = var.policies

  name        = each.key
  policy      = file("${var.path}/${each.value.policy_filename}")
  description = "Policy for ${each.value.description}"
}
```

In this case the `policies` variable is redefined as being a map, so you'd now present the name of each policy as the key within the map rather than as one of the attributes:

```
  policies = {
    cw = {
      policy_filename        = "cw.json"
      assume_policy_filename = "csasm.json"
      description            = "vpcflowlogs"
      owner                  = "vpc"
    }
    # ...
  }
```

Because the `for_each` value is the policies map, `each.key` inside the resource block is a policy name and `each.value` is the object representing that policy, making the resulting expressions easier to read and understand.

By using `for_each`, we will cause Terraform to create resource instance addresses like `aws_iam_policy.policy["cw"]` rather than like `aws_iam_policy.policy[1]`, and so adding and removing elements from the map will cause Terraform to add and remove corresponding instances from the resource, rather than try to update instances in-place to respect the list ordering as it would've done with your example.

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin.. This is much neater than mine